# mysql get changes of value on update

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this table with with no PK:

Columns:

```
id - number of id in table that was changed
action - what action was used (insert,update,delete) on row
name - new variable
who - who changed it
ts  - when was it changed
```

Table:

```
id    action    name        who      ts
2     insert    text        admin    2014-06-29 20:10:57
2     update    new_text    user     2014-06-29 20:10:57
2     delete    new_text    admin    2014-06-29 20:10:57
```

I am trying to get from this rows what was changed to what

Example:

```
id     action      name_from      name_to      who      ts
2      insert                     text         admin    2014-06-29 20:10:57
2      update      text           new_text     admin    2014-06-29 20:10:57
2      delete                                  admin    2014-06-29 20:10:57
```

I guess that insert and delete are easy because that is no previous variable, but the tricky one is update.

**My goal**: is to select variable name from last (insert,update to compare with new update.

This:

```
id     action      name_from      name_to      who      ts
2      update      text           new_text     admin    2014-06-29 20:10:57
```

**Problem:** To get previous value I use Timestamp when was change. In this case **timestam is same**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Introduce unique ID (PK) field or [milliseconds](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fractional-seconds.html) in your timestamp field.

This is problem that has been discussed already, you just search for it. There is reason why people have thought about [database table normalization](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-rdbms-concepts.htm) and I see no harm in adding more data to your table, if that is required by design of application.